# How can I debug a login denied?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote

I am having problems logging into a machine remotely using ssh. It allows me to enter the user name, but when I enter the password I get "Access denied." I can login using the same user/pw locally and I have successfully logged in to the same machine remotely before using the same username/pw. It is not the caps lock key.

How can I debug this problem and find the cause of the rejection? I have root on the box and can access it locally.

--- UPDATE

I found the page [OpenSSH logging wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging) to be extremely helpful and led to solving the problem.

The problem was that I had changed the sshd port to a different number and forgotten that I had done it. Oddly enough sshd was still listening on 22, but just rejecting any login attempts on that port. Not sure why that is.

Comment: Did you check logs? `/var/log/messages` `/var/log/syslog` `/var/log/security` - typical log destinations. Also enable debug mode for sshd by specifying `LogLevel DEBUG` in sshd_config. Also, DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent.  DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specify higher levels of debugging output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
ssh -v <host>
ssh -vv <host>
ssh -vvv <host>
```

That's where I'd start to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side debugging:

```
ssh -vvv
```

Server-side debugging:

```
tail -f /var/log/secure
```

Comment: Expanding on what these commands do and how they perform might help others that are looking for a solution but confused by these commands.

Answer (score 0):

By default SSH root access is disabled on most distros.  For security purposes I recommend keeping this setting unchanged and simply using a different account for SSH that you temporarily give root access.  However, if you do want access with the root account over SSH, first open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Next, comment out `PermitRootLogin`:

```
# PermitRootLogin no
```

Finally, restart ssh:

```
# /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: I am not trying to login as root over ssh. The account is a normal user account which has always worked before, and now it is giving me access denied, only when attempting to login remotely. I mentioned that I had root on the box just to make clear that I have full access to it for debugging purposes.

Comment: Try checking sshd_config if your account is allowed SSH access.